# Prolog - How to write all prolog answers to .txt file?

Tags: prolog

```
man(alan).
man(john).
man(george).

list_all:-
  man(X),
  write(X),
  fail.
```

Question `?-list_all` gives the answer:

```
alan
john
george
false
```

So I have all the men from the database. It works! My problem: I want to get the same list, but exported to `.txt` file. I tried to use this code to do this:

```
program  :-
  open('file.txt',write,X),
  current_output(CO),
  set_output(X),
  man(X),
  write(X),
  fail,
  close(X),
  set_output(CO).
```

The effect is: Program gives answer `false` and text: `alan john george` are not in `.txt` file - because of using `fail` predicate.

Is there an option to get all the items in the list into a `.txt` file (writing all options which are in database) without using `fail` predicate?

How can I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 8):

You're almost there. But the call to `fail/0` prevents the stream to be closed. Try for example:

```
program :-
    open('file.txt',write, Stream),
    (   man(Man), write(Stream, Man), fail
    ;   true
    ),
    close(Stream).
```

An alternative using the de facto standard `forall/2` predicate could be:

```
program :-
    open('file.txt',write, Stream),
    forall(man(Man), write(Stream,Man)),
    close(Stream).
```

, , ,

Comment: Thanks. Edited the code to fix the bug in the variable name and to avoid changing the output stream.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!   I will use tell/told predicate for write an file... It will be better I think. I have one more question... If I have two the same records in data base... for example: man(john). man(john). man(adam). man(george). and when I'am asking: ?- man(X)...the answer is: john, john, adam, george. Is there any possibility to get only john, adam, george answer without double john?

Comment: @Przemek: tell/told is very brittle. Just adopt the scheme above.

Comment: @Przemek: see the all-solutions predicates, in particular `setof/3`, to collect a *set* of solutions.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use your code with open and close predicates, but it doesn't work. The empty .txt file is created and the prolog answer (names of men) is written in compiler console.

Comment: I assume that you're refereeing to the changes for using `setof/3´? You need to post your new code in order to allow me and others to comment on it.

Comment: No, I am not using setof/3 yet. I know where is the problem. I divided  code to two pieces:                                      program :-
    open('file.txt',write, Stream),
    write,
    close(Stream).                                                                                                                  write:-                                                             (   man(Man), write(Stream, Man), fail
    ;   true
    ).

Comment: And it doesn't works, but if I have directly your code, it works... So I understand, that we can't dividing code with open Stream...

Comment: You need to change your predicate `write` to something like `my_write(Stream)` in order to pass the stream argument. Compiling your code above should have printed a singleton variable warning in the definition of your `write/0` predicate.

Comment: Yes! You're right :). It works ! Thank you so much for your help :). So I am going to create some XPCE interface now :).