# Write data to CSV file from swi-prolog code

Tags: csv, prolog, swi-prolog

How can I write data to CSV file from the prolog code below?

Thanks,

SB

```
run:-
   member(A,[a,b,c,d,e]),
   member(B,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
   write(A),write(' '),write(B),nl,
   fail.
run.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog - How to write all prolog answers to .txt file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674731/prolog-how-to-write-all-prolog-answers-to-txt-file)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm not sure whether that is a full duplicate. This question inquires into a specific format, i.e. CSV, that is not mentioned in the other question.

Comment: @WouterBeek Well, adding coma instead of space and changing the file extension? Does it make such a difference?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: CSV it's a standard format, and so easy to do right

Answer (score 2):

#### Simple solution

Since you are using SWI-Prolog, you can use the [CSV library](http://swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=csv).

```
?- use_module(library(csv)).
?- findall(row(A,B), (member(A, [a,b,c,d,e]), member(B, [1,2,3,4,5])), Rows), csv_write_file('output.csv', Rows).
```

As you can see, I do this in two steps:

1. I create terms of the form `row(A, B)`.
2. Then I hand those terms to `csv_write_file/2` which takes care of creating a syntactically correct output file.

#### Non-standard separators

In your question you are not writing a comma between `A` and `B` but a space. If you *really* want to use the space as a separator you can set this as an option:

```
csv_write_file('output.csv', Rows, [option(separator(0' )])
```

#### 'Unbalanced' arguments

Also, in your question you have more values for `B` than for `A`. You can write code that handles this, but there are several ways in which this can be dealt with. E.g., (1) you can fill missing cells with `nill`; (2) you can throw an exception if `same_length(As, Bs)` fails; (3) you can only write the 'full' rows:

```
length(As0, N1),
length(Bs0, N2),
N is max(N1, N2),
length(As, N),
append(As, _, As0),
length(Bs, N),
append(Bs, _, Bs0),
```